# Can you update your app on playstore through an api

Tags: android, reactjs, api, google-play

I'm just learning about making apps, I have a question can you update your app on playstore through an api? Without having your users to re-download the app.

Checked the rapid api platform for this issue

Comment: Nops. I think you need to upload a new build on the Play Store. you only can change the data response from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a new app version and release an update via the  [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks?hl=en). This is often used in automated continuous integration / delivery pipelines with tools like [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) or [Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/).

Per default, the Google Play Store will automatically download and install the updated app on your user's devices. Users can however disable automatic updates.

You can't circumvent a re-downlaod even if it happens automatically.

If some parts of your app change frequently, consider implementing those via a web view which embeds a website you control. You can change the content of the website remotely without requiring an app update.